# Swift: Perfect Server: How to send Push Notification?

Tags: push-notification, perfect

I'm using [PerfectlySoft Perfect-Notifications](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Notifications) and try to import it via the following:

```
.Package(
        url:"https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Notifications.git",
        majorVersion: 2)
```

but I always get the following error:

```
Packages/PerfectNotifications-2.1.2/Sources/NotificationPusher.swift:278:8: error: value of type 'NetTCPSSL' has no member 'initializedCallback'
```

Is there another way to import and use it? Or another way so send push notifications from swift server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem some time ago, it was caused by a problem with package dependency order, try to create a new fresh project:

```
mkdir test
cd test
swift package init
```

Now edit package.swift, add this package

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "test",
    dependencies: [ 
        .Package(url:"https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Notifications.git", majorVersion: 2)
    ]
)
```

Now you can build it:

```
swift build
```

Tell me if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

also you can check out my example of simple push server made with Swift Perfect Server and other "Perfect" tools. It can send pushes on android and on iOS devices and also has administration web page https://github.com/AlexShubin/SwiftPushServer